# Is it a good design if making a lot of function aliases and combine them anywhere?

Tags: scala, design-patterns, functional-programming

I'm working on a scala project which has very functional code. It defines a package object, and use `type` to define a lot of function type aliases, like:

```
package object updater {
    type FetchUser = UserSource => FetchFailed \/ FetchResult[BasicUser]
    type PublishUser = BasicUser => PublishFailed \/ OK
    type UpdateLastChangedUser = ChangedUser => DatabaseUpdateFailed[Change] \/ OK
    type GetMostRecentlyUpdatedUser = () => DatabaseGetFailed \/ Option[ChangedUser]
    type Continue = ChangedUser => Boolean
    type FetchUserChanges = Option[ChangedUser] => Continue => Stream[Failed \/ ChangedUser]
    type ChangeJobRunner = Job => Stream[Failed \/ ChangedUser] => BatchResult
}
```

Then, it defines a lot of class which extend these types, e.g.

```
case class MyFetchUser(httpClient:HttpClient) extends FetchUser {
    override def apply(userSource: UserSource): FetchFailed \/ FetchResult[BasicUser] = {
        // business code
    }
}

case class MyPublishUser(fetchUser: FetchUser) extends PublishUser { ... }
```

Finally, it will combine them together in some entry place.

I feel very strange about these code, since I never see this kind of way to organize code. From Java background, I used to organize code with some domain classes, and depend on each other:

```
case class UserFetcher(httpClient:HttpClient) {
    def fetch(...) = ???
}

case class PublishUser(userFetcher: UserFetcher) {
    def publish(...) = ???
}
```

How do you think about the former approach? Is it a good design to organize code like that?

Comment: Do you know is there any open-source scala project use the same way to organize code?

Comment: What is `\/`??? Exception or result?

Comment: It's the `Either` type from scalaz.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand "But with the first solution, I'm sure there are many functions can only be used in some class." I parse this as "there are many functions *that* can only be used in some class", and I suspect you mean that many functions are only needed in some class but aren't hidden in this design. However, I don't see how.

Comment: @Blaisorblade, your understanding is exactly correct. I mean if I use 2nd solution, I only need to pass some dependency objects(not functions) to some classes, and I can define methods just inside one class if possible, not exposed to "package" level

Comment: @Freewind: but your `UserFetcher` is a public member of the package, just like `type FetchUser`. Maybe the syntax is suggesting you otherwise, but that would be a misunderstanding.
`def fetch` is a public method, so it's still "exposed", that is, not encapsulated. Maybe you mean that `fetch` does not pollute the package namespace, while `FetchUser` does, but that compares to `UserFetcher`.

Comment: Moreover, the `UserFetcher` above is just a more verbose way to write a function type — except that since it's a case class, it also exposes `httpClient` as a public member.

In either case, if all uses of a type are local to some context, you can move the definitions inside that context: both classes and type aliases can be defined everywhere (a bit like with Java inner classes).

Comment: @Blaisorblade, yes, you are right, I think I can remove that sentence to make it clear :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't need to extend those function types the way you do here:

   ```
   case class MyFetchUser(httpClient:HttpClient) extends FetchUser {
       override def apply(userSource: UserSource): FetchFailed \/ FetchResult[BasicUser] = {
           // business code
       }
   }
   ```

   That's because in the code you give you are only defining `apply`. You can just as well write, where needed:

   ```
   val myFetchUser: FetchUser = userSource => { /*business code */ }
   ```

   or you can write a method creating the right `FetchUser` as needed:

   ```
   def getFetchUser(name: String): FetchUser =
     userSource => { /*business code to return users matching String */ }
   ```

   This stops being true only once you have other methods for those classes which are part of the interface.
2. The above shows that if you only need to use `myFetchUser` locally, you don't need to create a global class for it. If `myFetchUser` needs other functions, you can similarly define them locally.
3. This code is using the fact that, say, `FetchUser` is in essence just a function type, returning a `\/`. But that makes sense if this enables one to use general concepts available for functions, otherwise it's not clear there's a good point to it. And collecting these function types together in a package object seems to make even less sense.